# Creating a button that will notify me of the last “sReportNo”

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I got a database called “Reports” and I want to print the last “sReportNo”.

That’s the code:

```
SQLiteCommand CommandText = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Reports WHERE sReportNo = (SELECT MAX(sReportNo) FROM Reports)", conn);
SQLiteDataReader reader = commandText.ExecuteReader();
var lastReportNo = reader;
MessageBox.Show("Currently, there is " +lastReportNo+ " reports.");
```

And it prints “Currently, there is System.Data.SQLiteDataReader reports.”

Comment: Side note: Why not simply `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Reports ORDER BY sReportNo DESC`?

Comment: It tells me “database schema has changed” - “near “1”: syntax error”

Comment: I didn’t catch ya, so what I should I do? :) I have wrote exactly what you wrote

Comment: `"Currently, there is " +lastReportNo+ " reports."` will do `lastReportNo.ToString()` which results in the observed output. You need to advance the reader to the first result (if any) and then call one of the `Get...` overloads and ouput the result of that.

Comment: If you are expecting a single value result - consider using ExecuteScalar rather than ExecuteReader & then needing to read. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand.executescalar?view=msdata-sqlite-3.1.0

Comment: It prints me the whole SQLiteCommand, how do I save a single value and print it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve found the correct code:

```
SQLiteCommand commandText = new SQLiteCommand(“SELECT Count(*) FROM Reports ORDER BY sReportNo DESC”, conn);
var lastReportNo = commandText.ExecuteScalar();
MessageBox.Show("Currently, there is " + lastReportNo + " reports.");
```

Comment: If there is the possibility of records being deleted, you will get the wrong value. A better query would be _"SELECT TOP 1 sReportNo FROM Reports ORDER BY sReportNo DESC"_

Comment: Sorry I should have checked the exact syntax - _"SELECT sReportNo FROM Reports ORDER BY sReportNo DESC LIMIT 1"_  https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-limit/